# How to sort by closest number?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, yii2

I need to sort/order in php mysql table by closest values. For example, I have table with prices values:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

When I search for `37` it must return closest:

```
40
30
50
20
10
```

In details: `|40-37|=3` - closest. then `|30-37|=7` - next. then `|50-37|=13`. then `|20-37|=17`...
So we have `3, 7, 13, 17....`

Else, is there build-in way to do it on Yii2?

```
$query = Prices::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['price' => SORT_DESC]],
]);
```

Comment: You mean in all cases the 2 closest numbers desc then the rest desc?

Comment: I made in details how sort works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the SQL level, what you want to do is sort by the distance each row is from 37, e.g., `ORDER BY ABS(value - 37) ASC` (see [this SqlFiddle for an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11c42/6/0)).

To apply that within the Yii2 framework, you should be able to use that expression above in place of the column name for the sort hash's key:

```
$query = Prices::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['ABS(price - 37)' => SORT_ASC]],
]);
```

Now, assuming that the `37` is a parameter, you'll need to interpolate it into that expression. Make sure to sanitize it (e.g, `'ABS(price - ' . (int)$yourParam . ')'`), or else you'll be opening yourself up to SQL injection. Also, that `'sort'` value will only work with ActiveDataProvider; it won't work for, say, ArrayDataProvider.

Comment: @sirjay Are you using ActiveDataProvider or a different data provider? What database are you running on?

Comment: ActiveDataProvider (as on my code above). Mysql. Maybe we should try use something `$query->andFilterWhere(['...', 'price', $this->price]);` ?

Comment: I think I see. The `sort` implementation in Yii2 is probably trying to look up the column `ABS(price - 37)` on your model, which fails. Your suggestion about ordering the query before passing it to ADP sounds good, though... how about: `$query = Prices::find()->addOrderBy("ABS('price - 37') ASC")` ?

Comment: I made this `->addOrderBy('abs(price - 37) asc');` and now it works. ;S

Comment: Cool! Can you edit my answer with your working code?